# Destroy stateful widgets from tree in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am having a statefull widget named ListItem.
It displays total users from a list. I select some of the users and i want all those selected users to get deselected when i tap a send button. [image shows user list and selected user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4pIC.png).

How do i code to get that result, below code shows ListItem widget and UserListPage which displays my list.

```
final UserData user;
final ValueChanged<bool> isSelectedFun;
ListItem({
 required this.user,
 required this.isSelectedFun,
});

@override
_ListItemState createState() => _ListItemState();
}

class _ListItemState extends State<ListItem> {
var isSelected = false.obs;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return GetBuilder<UserListController>(
   init:UserListController(),
   builder: (controller) {
     return Column(
       children: [
         GestureDetector(
           onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                   isSelected.toggle();
           widget.isSelectedFun(isSelected.value);
                });
           //GroupSelController.to.update();
           },
           child: Obx((){
             return  ListTile(
              title: Text("${widget.user.name}",style: textbody14.copyWith(color:Colors.black),),
              trailing: isSelected.value
                ? Icon(
                        Icons.check_circle,
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      )
                :SizedBox()
            );
           }),
         ),
         Divider()
       ],
     );
   }
 );
}

 class UserListPage extends StatefulWidget {


@override
_UserListPageState createState() => _UserListPageState();
}

class _UserListPageState extends State<UserListPage> {



@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return GetBuilder<UserListController>(
   init: UserListController(),
   builder: (controller) {
     return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text("Users"),
         actions: [
          IconButton(onPressed: (){
            Get.find<AuthController>().signOut();
          }, 
          icon: Icon(Icons.logout))
         ],
       ),
       body: Container(
         height:Get.height,
         width:Get.width,
         child:Column(
           children: [
             Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
               children: [
                  controller.selCount > 0
           ?ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
               Get.dialog(msgDialog());
           }, child: Text("Send")):Text("Tap to select user/s")
               ],
             ),
             Obx((){
               return Column(
               children:List.generate(
                 controller.usersList.length, (index) {
                   return ListItem(
                       user: controller.usersList[index],
                       isSelectedFun: (bool value) {
                    
                       if (value) {
                         controller.selectedList.add(
                           controller.usersList[index]);
                           controller.update();
                       } else {
                         controller.selectedList.remove(
                           controller.usersList[index]);
                           controller.update();
                       }
                    
                     //print("$index : $value");
                   },
                     );
                 })
             );
             })
           ],
         )
       ),
     );
   }
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I got u well, u want kind of radio button feature.
You can use by giving index to them. For example:

```
       int selectedIndex = 0;
```

And for indicator icon, check it for each item:
For example, for one case:
if(selectedIndex==1) // show icon

And u can update selectedIndex on ontap to list item

Comment: thnks @BosS, this worked smoothly, i just replaced condition with this
`trailing:userListcontroller.selectedList.contains(widget.user)`